# Use Modernizr to add value attribute to email input

Tags: html, input, placeholder, modernizr

Struggling a little bit with the syntax. I've got an email form that has placeholder text set up. To support backwards compatibility, I'm using Modernizr to add the Value attribute to input, but without any success.

Ideas? Thanks for your help!

HTML:

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="corners" placeholder="Enter your email address" />
```

JavaScript:

```
if (!Modernizr.input.placeholder){
  setValue(document.getElementById('email'),'Enter your email address');
}
```

Comment: Where is your implementation of `setValue`?

Answer (score 1):

My initial thought was that the lack of placeholder support may present issues in manipulation of type="email" values. In setting up a quick [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fs8y9/4/) I was able to successfully update the value (testd in IE7).

I replaced your setValue helper name with makePlaceholder and used a very basic implementation in my example.

```
function makePlaceholder( el, placeholder ) {
    el.onfocus = function(){
        if( placeholder == el.value ) {
            el.value = '';
        }
    };
    el.onblur = function() {
        if( '' == el.value && placeholder != el.value ) {
            el.value = placeholder;
        }
    };
    el.value = placeholder;
}
```

Feel free to adapt this into your solution, hopefully it will help you out.

Comment: I think he probably wants to use Modernizr, which you are not doing.

Comment: Actually, it is what I'm doing. Have a read through my response, "I replaced your setValue helper name with makePlaceholder and used a very basic implementation in my example."